# Switch statement letter to integer

Tags: c, switch-statement, average

Assume that grades from A to F correspond to numbers from 1 to 6. Write a program that has three letter grades as inputs and prints the average numerical grade. My code looks like this : PS: I want this to print out the average of three letter inputs. (I take into account this code could be completely wrong, thus the final code should contain the "switch" and the calculation of the three corresponding values in numbers/interger. please help).

```
int main(){
char x,y,z;
int num;
float avg;
printf("\n Give three grades:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

switch(x,y,z){

case 'a': return 1;
break;
case 'b': return 2;
break;
case 'c': return 3;
break;
case 'd': return 4;
break;
case 'e': return 5;
break;
case 'f': return 6;
break;
}
avg = x+y+z /3;
printf("\n The average is: %d \n", avg);
return 0;
}`
```

Comment: thanks paddy. how could I solve this without the switch though (in a beginner skilled program fashion). Thanks again for the pointers

Comment: see my answer.  I used the ternary operator (`?:`) which is probably not a beginner thing.  You can do the same with `if .. else ..`.  If you don't know `tolower` you can do `grade-'A'` separate from `grade-'a'`.  I assumed you need to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I should point out that using `%d` in `scanf` will not read characters.  Perhaps you wanted `%c`.

Comment: Suggest `printf("\n The average is: %.1f\n", (x+y+z) / 3.0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only switch on one value at a time.  Why don't you make it a function:

```
int grade_value( char grade )
{
    switch(grade) {
       case 'a':
       case 'A':
          return 1;

       case 'b':
       case 'B':
          return 2;

       // etc...

       default:
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Then just call it for each of `x`, `y`, and `z`.  You really don't need to use a `switch` at all, but nevermind.  *eg*

```
int grade_value( char grade )
{
    int value = tolower(grade+1) - 'a';
    return (value >= 1 && value <= 6) ? value : 0;
}
```

Also, note that you should use `%f` to output a `float`, not `%d` (which outputs an `int`).

You've also misunderstood how `switch` works.  In your `main`, you switched and `return` from each `case`.  That would exit `main` and return a value.  That means your program would terminate.

You *can* use `return` in the function I suggested for you, because it's not your `main`.  It will immediately return the given value from the function, thus you don't need `break'.

Comment: It would be nice to explain how this can be done without the `switch` (as you have already mentioned it) and also to explain why the OP's code can be compiled. Just an advice.

Comment: Sure thing @KirilKirov, thanks.  I haven't mentioned the math errors.  I think just fixing the `switch` is the main scope of the question.